# How to return dataset and get the result from dataset in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, crystal-reports, dataset

How to return dataset and get the result using dataset in asp.net?
first i have a WCF class that contain dataset method, and it returned dataset result
here is my method

```
            string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        using (con = new SqlConnection(conString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spViewMasterTransaction", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            SqlParameter parameterEarlyDate = new SqlParameter();
            parameterEarlyDate.ParameterName = "@earlyDate";
            parameterEarlyDate.Value = earlyDate;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterEarlyDate);

            SqlParameter parameterLateDate = new SqlParameter();
            parameterLateDate.ParameterName = "@lateDate";
            parameterLateDate.Value = lateDate;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterLateDate);


            con.Open();

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            da.Fill(ds, "Master");
        }

        return ds;
```

it returned a dataset result, i used it in my datagridview, but i want to used it in my crystalreport, of course i can't use it just like how i used in winform datagridview, i think i have to catch the dataset value that returned from my wcf and store it in my client dataset.. how to do this? since, the asp.net doesn't have dataset component like winform?

Answer (score 0):

With CrystalReports you need to work with *DataTables* not *DataSets*

You can do something like this on your *cs* file:

```
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;
using CrystalDecisions.Shared;

    ReportDocument rptDoc = new ReportDocument();

    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // Get the DataTable form the DataSet               
            DataTable dt = yourDataSet.Tables[0];  // Or use the table name like this yourDataSet.Tables["TableName"];

            string reportPath = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/CrystalReport1.rpt");
            rptDoc.Load(reportPath);
            rptDoc.SetDataSource(dt);
            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptDoc;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblErrMsg.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // Clear error message if any.
            lblErrMsg.Text = "";

            // Crystal Report Fill
            DataTable dt = yourDataSet.Tables[0];
            rptDoc.SetDataSource(dt);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblErrMsg.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }

    protected void Page_UnLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            this.CrystalReportViewer1.Dispose();
            this.CrystalReportViewer1 = null;
            rptDoc.Close();
            rptDoc.Dispose();
            rptDoc = null;
            GC.Collect();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblErrMsg.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

And in your *aspx* file add something like this:

```
    <%@ Register Assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" Namespace="CrystalDecisions.Web" TagPrefix="CR" %>

    <CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1" runat="server" 
        AutoDataBind="True" DisplayStatusbar="False" 
        EnableDatabaseLogonPrompt="False" EnableDrillDown="False" 
        EnableParameterPrompt="False" EnableTheming="False" EnableToolTips="False" 
        GroupTreeStyle-ShowLines="False" HasDrilldownTabs="False" 
        HasDrillUpButton="False" HasGotoPageButton="False" 
        HasPageNavigationButtons="False" HasSearchButton="False" Height="894px" 
        SeparatePages="False" ToolPanelView="None" Width="918px" 
        GroupTreeImagesFolderUrl="" ReportSourceID="CrystalReportSource1" 
        ToolbarImagesFolderUrl="" ToolPanelWidth="200px" 
        HasToggleGroupTreeButton="False" HasToggleParameterPanelButton="False" />    
    <CR:CrystalReportSource ID="CrystalReportSource1" runat="server">
        <Report FileName="App_Data\CrystalReport1.rpt">
        </Report>
    </CR:CrystalReportSource>
```

I hope it helps.

Pablo